# Why is this "if" statement not triggering when it is supposed to?

Tags: c

I have this block of code and it's supposed to trigger a message when the user punches in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and enters it, but no message appears. Can someone explain to me why this is so?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int result = scanf( "%d", &i );
    if( result == EOF )
    {
        printf( "End of file detected\n" );
    }
}
```

It just doesn't seem to want to print my message when I punch in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> on the keyboard and entering the result `^D`.

Comment: How should I rework the syntax so it reads the ^D?

Comment: If you type any non-whitespace text then Ctrl D, it will not print "End of file detected\n".

Comment: Please note the correct procedure when getting an answer which you feel is correct, is to *mark the answer as accepted*. In particular, do not edit your post to say "solved: ..." (You might want to take the [Welcome To Stack Overflow Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) some time.)

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> is the Linux shortcut for EOF. On Windows press <kbd>F6</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Jesus christ... I dind't know that it was different on windows

Comment: I will give you check mark after 8 mins when it lets me do it.

Comment: @user152573 it's been more than the 8 minutes you mention; if this answer helped you, then please accept it using the check mark.